# Finding prime numbers in C

Tags: c, prime-factoring

I'm currently working with this problem and planning to not have functions.
but, I have a question.
Why initialize 1 to the identifier "prime"?

```
int main() { 
   int loop, number;
   int prime = 1;
   
   number = 11;

   for(loop = 2; loop < number; loop++) {
      if((number % loop) == 0) {
         prime = 0;
      }
   }

   if (prime == 1)
      printf("%d is prime number.", number);
   else
      printf("%d is not a prime number.", number);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Had `number` been less than 2, this code incorrectly reports that the number is prime.

Answer (score 1):

Because `1` is used in the condition `prime == 1` and therefore `1` means that the number is a prime number.

If you write the condition as `prime`, you can use any non-zero number that fits in `int` for prime flag (no divisor found flag). For example, You can use `1`, `42`, `200`, `334`, `555`, `777`, `999`, `2021`, `-1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`prime` is just a flag. If `prime` is 1, it means that `number` is prime. If `prime` is 0, it means that `number` is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

With initialising as `prime=1;` and the conditional output as

```
if (prime == 1)
      printf("%d is prime number.", number);
```

The logic here is "start by assuming the currently processed number is prime".
The code also has a `prime = 0;` which is excuted in a loop under a certain condition.
So there is many chances to reset to "is not prime".
This matches the concept of prime numbers. They are pirime if there are no other divisors.
The code looks for divisors. Any found means "not prime".
The reverse logic, i.e. assuming non-prime and then looking for reasons for prime does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your code now. I just changed the **variable name** and **data type** to **boolean**. Hope you can understand now.

```
 int main() { 
 int loop, number;
 bool numberIsPrime = true;
 number = 11;
 for(loop = 2; loop < number; loop++) {
   if((number % loop) == 0) {
      numberIsPrime = false;
   }
  }

 if ( numberIsPrime == true)
   printf("%d is prime number.", number);
 else
   printf("%d is not a prime number.", number);
 return 0;
}
```